# Can Thunderbird play sounds correctly on Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, email, thunderbird, notifications

I am trying to configure Thunderbird to play a sound when an email arrives and although i have set it there is no sound.

When I try to test a sound via the `Play` button, the sound is not played.

Is there some place where Thunderbird needs to be configured to play sounds? Like in `about:config`?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with KDE.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but are you able to play sound normally?

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes

Comment: Thanks and no worries, you're not the only one with this problem apparently ;) see if this link might provide any pointers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141765/no-sound-with-thunderbird-12-0-1

Comment: Your comment led me to a fix. You might want to answer it.